# Running Semi-Supervised Learning Image Classification Code and Encountering Errors

Tags: artificial-intelligence

error：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aavWg.png)
"I have tried running the code from the ACPL paper and encountered this error. Could some experts please help me with remote debugging or guide me on how to resolve it? My email (at) is: 907556021 (at) qq.com. I would sincerely appreciate any assistance. Thank you very much!"